# iOS Metal requires constant in fragment function

Tags: ios, shader, fragment-shader, metal

I'm trying to understand Apple's Metal and converting some old opengl shaders. I'm stuck in an error that appears only in one project and not the others. I wanted to ask if there is a compiler option or something like that, that I do not know and can cause this error.

So... I've got an audio visualizer for a music player that I wrote sometime ago using opengl on ndk for Android. I converted the shader to metal on an empty project. The fragment method signature is like this:

```
fragment float4 spectrum_fragment_func(
      Vertex vert [[stage_in]], 
      device Fragment *uniforms [[buffer(0)]], 
      device float *left [[buffer(1)]], 
      device float *right [[buffer(2)]]
)
```

I'm updating the Fragment object in code. It has a "time" value and needs to be updated for the effects to take place, meaning I cannot use constant values.

Shader compiles and works without any problems on the test application, that simply has a ViewController and my MTKView class.

When I copy the classes and shaders as-is to another project, I start getting this error:

```
/Volumes/Additional/Projects/.../Visuals/Shaders.metal:31:189: 
Pointer argument to fragment function must be const
```

If I convert the Fragment variable to constant, this time error appears for the next value in the signature. It seems that in this project, something is changed and does not accept any other types of variables but only consts...

If anyone had a similar problem, or know how to solve this I'm stuck and need some help.

Comment: maybe try uniform ?

Comment: If it works in one project but not another than I would first check to make sure it's using the same version of metal, then ensure you don't have any variable name conflicts, also you should check to make sure the shaders are in the right assemblies.